# Downloading a data frame from Shiny a App as a txt file

Tags: r, shiny, download

This is my first time here in stack overflow. I apologize for the generic title of my question, but I couldn't think of any other title that wouldn't be too cumbersome. I am struggling to download the results of data frame generated in shiny as a txt file.

Below is an example of what I have done and what I would like to do.

This is what I have done in Shiny:

```
##################################
## Load R packages ###############
##################################
library(dplyr)
library(tictoc)
library(lubridate)
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(zoo)

##################################
## create data for the example ###
##################################

df <- data.frame(date = as.Date((Sys.Date()-9):Sys.Date())
                 ,id = sample.int(10)
                 ,amount = rnorm(10, -1000, 300))
mapping <- data.frame(id = 1:10
                      ,Company = c("XP", "Itau", "Brad", "Paddy", "XYZ", "Tuco", "Sant", "Rolex", "ABC", "TaG")
                      ,Country = c("BR", "BR", "BR", "IR", "ES", "IT", "AG", "SW", "NO", "CY"))

##################################
############ Define UI ###########
##################################

ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"), 
                navbarPage(
                  "PoG",
                  tabPanel("Filter",
                           sidebarLayout(
                             sidebarPanel(
                               dateRangeInput("dates",tags$h3("Date Range:") ,
                                              start = as.Date(Sys.Date()-10),
                                              end = as.Date(Sys.Date()) )

                             ), # sidebarPanel
                             mainPanel(
                               h1("Filtered values"),

                               h4("Summary Table"),
                               DT::dataTableOutput("Final")

                             ) # mainPanel
                          ) # sidebar Panel
                      )# sidebar Layout
                ) # navbarPage
                , downloadButton("export_data", "Download")
                ) # fluidPage


##################################
#### Server Function UI ##########
##################################  

Server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$Final <- DT::renderDataTable({

    df %>% filter(date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2])
  })

  }

##################################
#### Create Shiny object #########
##################################  

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = Server)
```

This is what I would like to happen once the download button is pressed:

```
 Records <- 1:dim(df %>% filter(date >= input$dates[1] & date <= input$dates[2]))[1]

    Tst <- data.frame(test = rep("", length(Records) * 9))
    Tst$test <-as.character(Tst$test)

for (i in 1:length(Records)){

      position <- which(mapping$id %in% df$id[i])
      Entity <- as.character(mapping$Company[position])
      Country <- as.character(mapping$Country[position])
      DealDate <- format(df$date[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
      Dealer <- "SvcUser"
      Comments <- paste0(Entity," ", Country)


      Tst$test[i + (i-1) * 8]   <- "@ActualDeal"
      Tst$test[i+1 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("** RECORD ",Records[i])
      Tst$test[i+2 + (i-1) * 8] <- "$NEW"
      Tst$test[i+3 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("Entity=",Entity)
      Tst$test[i+4 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("DealDate=",DealDate)
      Tst$test[i+5 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("Dealer = ", Dealer)
      Tst$test[i+6 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("Comments=",Comments)
      Tst$test[i+7 + (i-1) * 8] <- "$INSERT"
      Tst$test[i+8 + (i-1) * 8] <-  ""           


    }


output$export_data <- downloadHandler(
      filename = "test.qxt"
      , content = function(){
        write.table(Tst, file = "test.txt", row.names = F, sep = "\t", col.names = F, quote = F)
      }


      )
```

I am struggling in saving the object Tst as a text file when the download button in the app is pressed.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you need exactly. Am I correct that you do know what should happen but you do not know how to trigger the action? Please confirm or correct me.

Comment: Hi Jan. You are correct. I want the above code to be triggered once the user press the download button in the Shiny app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by doing the following:

1st: I created two functions

Function 1:

```
FilterData <- function(x1, x2){

  Result <- df %>% filter(date >= x1 & date <= x2)

}
```

Function 2:

```
PrintTable <- function(x1, x2){

  Records <- 1:dim(df %>% filter(date >= x1 & date <= x2))[1]

    Tst <- data.frame(test = rep("", length(Records) * 9))
    Tst$test <-as.character(Tst$test)
    for (i in 1:length(Records)){

      position <- which(mapping$id %in% df$id[i])
      Entity <- as.character(mapping$Company[position])
      Country <- as.character(mapping$Country[position])
      DealDate <- format(df$date[i], "%d/%m/%Y")
      Dealer <- "SvcUser"
      Comments <- paste0(Entity," ", Country)


      Tst$test[i + (i-1) * 8]   <- "@ActualDeal"
      Tst$test[i+1 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("** RECORD ",Records[i])
      Tst$test[i+2 + (i-1) * 8] <- "$NEW"
      Tst$test[i+3 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("Entity=",Entity)
      Tst$test[i+4 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("DealDate=",DealDate)
      Tst$test[i+5 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("Dealer = ", Dealer)
      Tst$test[i+6 + (i-1) * 8] <- paste0("Comments=",Comments)
      Tst$test[i+7 + (i-1) * 8] <- "$INSERT"
      Tst$test[i+8 + (i-1) * 8] <-  ""           


    }

    return(Tst)
}
```

Then I changed the Server function as follows:

```
Server <- function(input, output, session) {

  x1 <- reactive(input$dates[1])
  x2 <- reactive(input$dates[2])

  output$Final <- DT::renderDataTable({
    FilterData(x1(), x2())

  })



    data <- reactive({

      Test <- PrintTable(x1(), x2())

      return(Test)

      })




  output$export_data <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("test.txt")  },

    content = function(file) {
      write.table(data(), file, row.names = F, sep = "\t", col.names = F, quote = F)
    }
  )




}
```

Job Done!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case in my app. I simply linked it to an output and it worked for me:

```
output$MyOutput <- renderPrint({
  req(input$export_data) # Ensure that export_data value is available

  # Replace the next instructions with your own code
  Data <- fromJSON(file = input$export_data$datapath)
  # ... more code to correctly transform my data 
  print(Data)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer with me Jan. I will have a go at it once I am home and will let you know if it worked for.me.

Comment: Hi Jan, I tried your solution, but I am still not able to generate the txt file via the app. I am sure this is due to my own limitations and not your suggestion. Would you be able to show me how to do it by using the code I provided please?